# How to display a tooltip while selecting for zoom

Tags: highcharts

While selecting a range for zooming a Highcharts chart, I'd like to be able to display a tooltip showing the limits of the selected range (min/max x for zoomType x; min/max x and y for zoomType xy).

Is this possible and how would I go about implementing it?  Is there for example an event that is fired repeatedly while selection is in progress?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch setExtremes() function and implement your custom tooltip (i.e as a div)

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.events.setExtremes

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to work - setExtremes doesn't get called until after selection is complete - see http://jsfiddle.net/mDepn/